# How can I use gcc by installing Cygwin on a Windows machine?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin

i have installed the `cygwin` package for my netbeans IDE. I can use that in netBeans project. But now I want to use the gcc compiler from a cmd prompt. How can I do that?

In Linux we open a terminal and type

```
gcc filename.c
```

and it compiles. Now I want to do the same thing in Windows with Cygwin's gcc.   Can I type `gcc filename.c` in cmd and it compiles? If so, how?

**Edit :**

by writing in cmd

```
gcc --version
```

I get `Access is denied`

**Edit 1:** 
In the C: drive I have a folder named `Cygwin` that contains `Cygwin.bat`.

When I run that, a new prompt is opened and inside that when I type `gcc filename.c`, it works.

In that `.bat` file  :

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
```

I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Check that gcc is actually installed. `gcc --version`

Comment: Are you trying to run it from the Windows command prompt or from a Cygwin bash shell?

Comment: For what it's worth, you may find mingw to be a more natural gcc port

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hey gcc --version also says access denied.

Comment: @KeithThompson hey when i am trying it with cmd its says access is denied but cygwin bash bin works fine...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see from your latest comment that it works when you run `gcc` from the Cygwin bash shell.

The `Access is denied` message was appearing when you tried to run `gcc` from the Windows cmd prompt.  I don't know why you'd get that particular message.

My advice is just to use the bash shell.  (It also has a lot of nice features that the Windows command shell lacks.)  If that's a good solution for you, feel free to stop reading now.

But if you really want to use Cygwin tools (such as gcc) from a Windows prompt, you need to update your Windows `%PATH%` to include the Cygwin bin directory.  As seen from bash, the directory is `/usr/bin/`; from Windows, it's going to be something like `C:\cygwin\bin` (assuming you installed Cygwin in `C:\cygwin`, which is the default).

To permanently add `C:\cygwin\bin` to your Windows `%PATH%`, open `System Properties` in the Control Panel, tap the "Environment variables" button, and adjust the value of `Path` in "System variables".  Once you've done that, newly opened cmd windows should have the new `%PATH%` setting.  (The user interface for modifying environment variables isn't exactly use-friendly; maybe somebody else can suggest a better way.)

**EDIT:**

The `cygwin.bat` batch file changes the current director to `C:\cygwin\bin` and then launches the Cywgwin bash shell in a new window.  That gives you an environment in which `gcc` works by default, since your `$PATH` is already set up correctly.  The windows command shell and the Cygwin bash shell are quite different environments.

Comment: +1 The best tool I know for modifying environment variables is [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about). One tip is to set the compatibility options to "run as admin" on the exe to save you doing the right click shuffle every time you run it

Comment: i have already set path variable as you have suggested but gcc doesnot work in cmd.. but i am going with solution of bash. just typing bash in cmd, gcc works fine and i am comfortable witn it..!

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the gcc package for cygwin, you should be able to do simply `gcc filename.c`.

The `setup.exe` file of Cygwin lets you choose any additional package you want to add when installing. If you skipped it, simply rerun the `setup.exe`.

Packages can be also found on the [Cygwin website](http://cygwin.com/packages/).

Comment: writting  gcc filename.c says "Access is denied"

Comment: What directory are you working in? Do you have write access there?

Answer (score 1):

does your cmd recognizes gcc as an installed application?
if so, try this

```
gcc -c filename.c -o filename.o
```

Answer (score 0):

gcc is actually a link (which the Command Prompt does not understand). Use gcc-3 or gcc-4 if you need to use the Command Prompt.