# Visual Studio Code C/C++ Compile Run extension compiling error

Tags: c++, cygwin, cygwin-64

I can't compile my code using the "C/C++ Compile Run" extension
I press F6 and then i get the following Error:

`"...cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin11/cc1plus.exe:error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"`

I am using cygwin64 compiler and running on windows 7

Extension settings:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "E:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "C_Cpp.files.exclude": {
        
        "**/.vscode": true,
        "**/.vs": true
    },
    "terminal.integrated.useWslProfiles": false,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "Cygwin": { 
            "path": "E:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe",
            "args": ["-"],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd",
            "name": "Cygwin"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.cwd": ".../Cproject",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "",
    "c-cpp-compile-run.cpp-compiler": "E:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe",
    "c-cpp-compile-run.c-compiler": "E:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe"
}
```

The libraries:

```
 ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77930000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x77810000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fefd630000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x7fed81a0000)
        cyggmp-10.dll => /usr/bin/cyggmp-10.dll (0x3ff7b0000)
        cygiconv-2.dll => /usr/bin/cygiconv-2.dll (0x3ff670000)
        cygintl-8.dll => /usr/bin/cygintl-8.dll (0x3ff640000)
        cygisl-23.dll => /usr/bin/cygisl-23.dll (0x3fe960000)
        cygmpc-3.dll => /usr/bin/cygmpc-3.dll (0x3fe930000)
        cygmpfr-6.dll => /usr/bin/cygmpfr-6.dll (0x3ff490000)
        cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll (0x3ff870000)
        cygz.dll => /usr/bin/cygz.dll (0x3fedc0000)
        cygzstd-1.dll => /usr/bin/cygzstd-1.dll (0x3fed10000)
```

In addition, these are the packages i installed within cygwin

```
curl 8.2.1-1
gcc-core 11.4.0-1
gcc-g++ 11.4.0-1
gdb 12.1-1
git 2.39.0-1
libSDL-devel 1.2.15-3
libopencv-devel 3.4.1-3
make 4.4.1-2
wget 1.21.4-1
zip 3.0-13
```

I've tried a few solutions such as reinstalling cygwin, reinstalling the extension and i've checked the system environment variable PATH and there was nothing wrong with it

still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: VSCode is a tool that's designed for experienced developers. It requires convoluted, arcane configuration settings entered by manually-edited JSON file, that even experienced developers occasionally struggle with. It is not designed for beginners. It would not surprise me to learn that it simply no longer works on old, no longer supported platforms like Windows 7.

Comment: Try following the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) from the documentation. I wouldn't be surprised if invoking a cygwin compiler from windows doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik

I see, are there any other text editors that are more beginner-friendly and work well on windows 7? I've tried installing Atom, but i think it was shut down.

Comment: @AlanBirtles [Seems to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107052/how-can-i-use-gcc-by-installing-cygwin-on-a-windows-machine)…

Comment: @Ziad - Sam will just recommend using Linux instead. :-) On WIndows, the easiest install is Visual Studio Community, which comes with everything included and configured from the start. Just run the installer, and you are good to go.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Well, the terminal itself is working fine and i am able to compile the code and run it, but the extension isn't working, i don't wanna type two commands every time i make the smallest change to my code if i can just press F6.

Comment: Try launching VS Code from a cygwin shell.

Comment: @BoP I guess i will try Linux instead then, thanks a lot.

Comment: That's right, on MS-Windows C++ will always be a 2nd-class citizen, with Microsoft preferring that you use C# instead. All Linux distributions include the latest version of gcc, and a wide variety of editors and development tools.

Comment: Joining @BoP – MSVS is *beginner friendly*, indeed. Though in my eyes not a good IDE (still, even though it admittedly advanced quite a lot in the recent years) – I personally would go with two of, MSVS to be able to quickly start coding and one of the superior ones (that impose the task of initial configuration on you, though – which you could do whenever you're in the mood for). I personally liked [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), so didn't fit my personal needs, which currently does best [eclipse](https://eclipseide.org/) (any yes, some might want to kill me for…) and then there's

Comment: e.g. [Apache Net beans](https://netbeans.apache.org/). JetBrains yet offers [clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) (heard some good of a few times, never tried myself) but that's *not for free*.

Comment: @Aconcagua that post refers to running inside the cygwin shell, this isn't what's being done here which is possibly why it's not working

Comment: Alright, i will try using code blocks or just install Linux.

Thank you all for your help, appreciate it! :)

Comment: @molbdnilo Eh, No luck, thanks for your comment.